# Why don't all the shell processes in my promises (start blocks) run? (Is this a bug?)

Tags: raku

I want to run multiple shell processes, but when I try to run more than 63, they hang. When I reduce `max_threads` in the thread pool to `n`, it hangs after running the `n`<sup>th</sup> shell command.

As you can see in the code below, the problem is not in `start` blocks per se, but in `start` blocks that contain the `shell` command:

```
#!/bin/env perl6
my $*SCHEDULER = ThreadPoolScheduler.new( max_threads => 2 );

my @processes;

# The Promises generated by this loop work as expected when awaited
for @*ARGS -> $item {
    @processes.append(
        start { say "Planning on processing $item" }
    );
}

# The nth Promise generated by the following loop hangs when awaited (where n = max_thread)
for @*ARGS -> $item {
    @processes.append(
        start { shell "echo 'processing $item'" }
    );
}
await(@processes);
```

Running `./process_items foo bar baz` gives the following output, hanging after `processing bar`, which is just after the `n`<sup>th</sup> (here `2`<sup>nd</sup>) thread has run using `shell`:

> ```
> Planning on processing foo
> Planning on processing bar
> Planning on processing baz
> processing foo
> processing bar
> ```

What am I doing wrong? Or is this a bug?

Perl 6 distributions tested on CentOS 7:
  Rakudo Star 2018.06
  Rakudo Star 2018.10
  Rakudo Star 2019.03-RC2
  Rakudo Star 2019.03

With Rakudo Star 2019.03-RC2, `use v6.c` versus `use v6.d` did not make any difference.

Comment: Starting a loop block  `start {say "Starting $item"; loop (my $i=0; $i<100000; $i++) {state $a++;} }` runs up to the maximum number of threads in the pool. If there are more jobs than threads, the remainder wait for a free thread and then execute, as expected. For my two cents worth, your question highlights a bug.

Comment: @drclaw Thanks! I've updated my question to try to highlight the difference between when it works (as you demonstrate) and when it seems "buggy".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `shell` and `run` subs use `Proc`, which is implemented in terms of `Proc::Async`. This uses the thread pool internally. By filling up the pool with blocking calls to `shell`, the thread pool becomes exhausted, and so cannot process events, resulting in the hang.

It would be far better to use `Proc::Async` directly for this task. The approach with using `shell` and a load of real threads won't scale well; every OS thread has memory overhead, GC overhead, and so forth. Since spawning a bunch of child processes is not CPU-bound, this is rather wasteful; in reality, just one or two real threads are needed. So, in this case, perhaps the implementation pushing back on you when doing something inefficient isn't the worst thing.

I notice that one of the reasons for using `shell` and the thread pool is to try and limit the number of concurrent processes. But this isn't a very reliable way to do it; just because the current thread pool implementation sets a default maximum of 64 threads does not mean it always will do so.

Here's an example of a parallel test runner that runs up to 4 processes at once, collects their output, and envelopes it. It's a little more than you perhaps need, but it nicely illustrates the shape of the overall solution:

```
my $degree = 4;
my @tests = dir('t').grep(/\.t$/);
react {
    sub run-one {
        my $test = @tests.shift // return;
        my $proc = Proc::Async.new('perl6', '-Ilib', $test);
        my @output = "FILE: $test";
        whenever $proc.stdout.lines {
            push @output, "OUT: $_";
        }
        whenever $proc.stderr.lines {
            push @output, "ERR: $_";
        }
        my $finished = $proc.start;
        whenever $finished {
            push @output, "EXIT: {.exitcode}";
            say @output.join("\n");
            run-one();
        }
    }
    run-one for 1..$degree;
}
```

The key thing here is the call to `run-one` when a process ends, which means that you always replace an exited process with a new one, maintaining - so long as there are things to do - up to 4 processes running at a time. The `react` block naturally ends when all processes have completed, due to the fact that the number of events subscribed to drops to zero.