# Raku shell function within start block won't end

Tags: raku

Why doesn't the shell function end after executing the command `echo $i` in start ?

Code:

```
my $*SCHEDULER = ThreadPoolScheduler.new(:max_threads(2));
my @promises = (^10).map: -> $i {
    start {
        shell("echo $i");  # pending here
        say "after shell";
    }
};
await @promises;
```

It outputs:

0
1

Comment: possible duplicate answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55265176/why-dont-all-the-shell-processes-in-my-promises-start-blocks-run-is-this-a

Comment: Please reformulate the question. For instance, why are you using that particular program? (which is similar to the one indicated in the answer by @MobrineHayde) Why do you set `max_threads` to 2 and then start 10 promises? What does exactly happen? How is it different to that question? Do you observe it hangs, just like the person that created that question does? Also, doesn't it print "after shell"? Please clarify so that we can reopen it

Comment: The author of the question approved the close vote.